# Analyze SQL query in DBeaver

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I would like to get some info about a running query to analyze it. In PgAdmin 3 I could at least use 'Explain Query', while in DBeaver, after clicking 'Explain Execution Plan', nothing happens.

How to obtain any information about query in DBeaver?

@Edit

Sorry if this question seems too broad. I don't expect explanation of how to analyze the query, I just would like to know if it is possible to open an analyzer in DBeaver and how to do it.

Comment: Just run `explain (analyze) select ...`  to see the execution plan. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you add it as answer, please? I'll accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 16):

The shortcut does not work for me. Use a mouse-click instead:

[image]

Example with

```
SELECT 1;
```

[image]

Or use the EXPLAIN command:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 1;
```

[image]

A longer query could look like this, see https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Query-Execution-Plan/ as said in the other answer as well:

#### Simple plan view

[image]

#### Advanced plan view

> In DBeaver Lite, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions you can use an
> advanced (graph) visualization of the execution plan. This
> visualization shows the most expensive (cost-based) plan nodes. You
> can hide all irrelevant nodes (see node details), use horizontal or
> vertical plan layouts, export it to an image or save it as JSON to
> send to a colleague.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Click on a query and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Query-Execution-Plan/